# ACPI startup error on ubuntu 11.10 but worked on 11.04

Tags: 11.10, 11.04, startup, acpi

i have looked around quite a bit for an issue like this, but cant find anything.

I had Ubuntu 11.04 running on my desktop with no issues.  I then formated the drive to install 11.10.
I managed to get 11.10 installed using ACPI=off command on the install menu.
I now need to add the same command on each stat up (using 'e' on the boot menu) and the system wont shut down without me pushing the power button.

Is there no way i can use ACPI config of Ubuntu 11.04?

I'm running an intel motherboard pendium 4.

Thanks in advance.

Tristan.

Comment: What error do you get? If you disable ACPI, certain features won't work, possibly the power button, suspend and power management.

Answer (score 1):

Boot from a live medium and follow the instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A2nd_option_%3a_install_Boot-Repair_in_Ubuntu) to install boot-repair. Then go [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#Using_Boot-Repair) and follow the instructions to run boot-repair, using the "Advanced options" section of that article to help you automatically add `acpi=off` to the default boot options.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  Will setting acpi to off mean that i will have to push the power button to turn my machine off after clicking shut down for always?  Is there no way to use Ubuntu 11.04s acpi system?

Answer (score 0):

Install Grub Customizer to your system so you can edit the boot sequence from your desktop. Here is a tutorial to install Grub Customizer: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-grub-customizer-in-ubuntu-13-04.html

Go to General Settings > Advanced so you can add/remove the ACPI=off parameter with Grub Customizer. Save changes and reboot.

FYI, on my configuration (Nvidia 9600 graphic card on Macbook Pro 5,3), I can't use the ACPI for now because the desktop freezes after a minute or two. Beware you don't get the same trouble.